# Update some fieds using Prisma

Tags: nestjs, backend, prisma, dto

I have a NestJS project with Prisma, and I'm trying to update a model using 'CompanyUpdateInput' but I'm getting the error:

```
this.prisma.company.update({
          where: {
            id: '6cbd0967-9ed3-4754-9967-d89df291fc3f'
          },
          data: {
            id: '6cbd0967-9ed3-4754-9967-d89df291fc3f',
            addressStreet: undefined,
            addressNumber: undefined,
            addressZipCode: undefined,
            AddressNeighborhood: {
            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
              connect: {
                id: undefined
              }
            },
            Person: {
            ~~~~~~
              connect: {
                id: '150e1fc7-2881-46fd-914e-3e090e824cc4'
              },
              update: {
                name: 'Empresa Teste22',
                cpfCnpj: undefined,
                photo: undefined,
                isActive: undefined
              }
            }
          }
        })


Unknown arg `Person` in data.Person for type CompanyUncheckedUpdateInput. Did you mean `personID`?
```

The code:

**schema.prisma**

```
model Company {
  id       String @id @default(dbgenerated("gen_random_uuid()")) @db.Uuid
  personID String @db.Uuid
  Person   Person @relation(fields: [personID], references: [id])

  addressStreet         String
  addressNumber         String
  addressNeighborhoodID String       @db.Uuid
  AddressNeighborhood   Neighborhood @relation(fields: [addressNeighborhoodID], references: [id])
  addressZipCode        String

  createdAt    DateTime       @default(now())
  updatedAt    DateTime       @updatedAt
  User         User[]
  Delivery     Delivery[]
  CompanyBlock CompanyBlock[]

  @@map("companies")
}

model Person {
  id        String  @id @default(dbgenerated("gen_random_uuid()")) @db.Uuid
  name      String
  cpfCnpj   String  @unique
  photo     String?
  isActive  Boolean @default(true)
  telephone String  @default("")
  cellphone String  @default("")

  createdAt DateTime  @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime  @updatedAt
  User      User[]
  Company   Company[]

  @@map("persons")
}
```

**CompanyDTO**

```
export class UpdateCompanyDTO {
  @ApiProperty()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  id: string;

  @ApiProperty()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  personID: string;

  @IsNotEmpty()
  @Length(10, 100)
  @ApiProperty()
  name: string;

  @ApiPropertyOptional()
  cpfCnpj: string;

  @IsOptional()
  @ApiPropertyOptional()
  photo: string;

  @ApiPropertyOptional()
  isActive: boolean;

  @ApiPropertyOptional()
  addressStreet: string;

  @ApiPropertyOptional()
  addressNumber: string;

  @ApiPropertyOptional()
  addressZipCode: string;

  @ApiPropertyOptional()
  addressNeighborhoodID: string;
}
```

**Prisma.CompanyUpdateInput**

```
export type CompanyUpdateInput = {
    id?: StringFieldUpdateOperationsInput | string
    addressStreet?: StringFieldUpdateOperationsInput | string
    addressNumber?: StringFieldUpdateOperationsInput | string
    addressZipCode?: StringFieldUpdateOperationsInput | string
    createdAt?: DateTimeFieldUpdateOperationsInput | Date | string
    updatedAt?: DateTimeFieldUpdateOperationsInput | Date | string
    Person?: PersonUpdateOneRequiredWithoutCompanyNestedInput
    AddressNeighborhood?: NeighborhoodUpdateOneRequiredWithoutCompanyNestedInput
    User?: UserUpdateManyWithoutCompanyNestedInput
    Delivery?: DeliveryUpdateManyWithoutCompanyNestedInput
    CompanyBlock?: CompanyBlockUpdateManyWithoutCompanyNestedInput
  }
```

**Prisma.CompanyUncheckedUpdateInput**

```
  export type CompanyUncheckedUpdateInput = {
    id?: StringFieldUpdateOperationsInput | string
    personID?: StringFieldUpdateOperationsInput | string
    addressStreet?: StringFieldUpdateOperationsInput | string
    addressNumber?: StringFieldUpdateOperationsInput | string
    addressNeighborhoodID?: StringFieldUpdateOperationsInput | string
    addressZipCode?: StringFieldUpdateOperationsInput | string
    createdAt?: DateTimeFieldUpdateOperationsInput | Date | string
    updatedAt?: DateTimeFieldUpdateOperationsInput | Date | string
    User?: UserUncheckedUpdateManyWithoutCompanyNestedInput
    Delivery?: DeliveryUncheckedUpdateManyWithoutCompanyNestedInput
    CompanyBlock?: CompanyBlockUncheckedUpdateManyWithoutCompanyNestedInput
  }
```

**company.service.ts:**

```
async updateCompany(companyID: string, data: UpdateCompanyDTO) {

    const companyUpdateInput: Prisma.CompanyUpdateInput = {
      id: companyID,
      updatedAt: new Date(),
      Person: {
        connect: {
          id: data.personID,
        },
        update: {
          name: data.name,
          cpfCnpj: data.cpfCnpj || undefined,
          isActive: data.isActive || undefined,
        },
      },
      addressStreet: data.addressStreet || undefined,
      addressNumber: data.addressNumber || undefined,
      addressZipCode: data.addressZipCode || undefined,

      AddressNeighborhood: {
        connect: {
          id: data.addressNeighborhoodID || undefined,
        },
      },
    };


    await this.companyRepository.update(companyID, companyUpdateInput),


    return true;
  }
```

**caompany.repository**

```
async update(id: string, data: Prisma.CompanyUpdateInput): Promise<Company> {
    return this.prisma.company.update({
      where: {
        id,
      },
      data,
    });
  }
```

After read the Prisma's documentation, I realized what's happening but I didn't figured out how to solve.

I'm sending a `CompanyUpdateInput` with some undefined values and for this reason, Prisma is using the `CompanyUncheckedUpdateInput` model instead `CompanyUpdateInput`, even the `CompanyUpdateInput` being the type of my object.

But sometimes I want to update all the field and sometimes no.

So, how can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in this blog: https://ruheni.dev/writing/skipping-connect-fields-for-unique-fields/

To solve the problem, I have to put the `&&` operator in Person and `AddressNeighborhood`. And I can remove the `|| undefined` too

```
async updateCompany(companyID: string, data: UpdateCompanyDTO) {

    const companyUpdateInput: Prisma.CompanyUpdateInput = {
      id: companyID,
      updatedAt: new Date(),
      Person: data.personID && {
        connect: {
          id: data.personID,
        },
        update: {
          name: data.name,
          cpfCnpj: data.cpfCnpj,
          isActive: data.isActive,
        },
      },
      addressStreet: data.addressStreet,
      addressNumber: data.addressNumber,
      addressZipCode: data.addressZipCode,

      AddressNeighborhood: data.addressNeighborhoodID && {
        connect: {
          id: data.addressNeighborhoodID,
        },
      },
    };
```